# RegEx for selecting WORD when it's not between double-quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, double, quote

What is the appropriate RegEx ( javascript ) for selecting 'and' when it's not between double-quotes.
like below:

> def abc as "Hello and Welcome" and aaa as "Hi" and bbb as "and"

"and"s which are not included in double-quotes should be selected like below:

> def abc as "Hello and Welcome" **and** aaa as "Hi" **and** bbb as "and"

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it works like a charm

`and(?=[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)`

It assumes if there are pairs of double quotes after `and` then this `and` is not in double quotes.

For demonstration have a look [here](https://regexr.com/49l9k)

Comment: Thanks. You've helped me so much.